# Hystrix fallback not getting called when using along with Feign

Tags: spring-boot, hystrix, feign, fallback, netflix-ribbon

I am creating a springboot application.I have 2 applications Producer and Consumer.
I am using Hystrix and Feign together. When I am calling wrong producer endpoint then fallback is not executing instead it is giving 404 path not found exception. Please help

Here is the code snippet

**Producer**
**bootstrap.properties**

```
spring.application.name=cst-employee-producer
```

**PizzaController.java**

```
@RestController
public class PizzaController {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;
    
    private static Map<Integer, PizzaOrderEntity> mapOfPizzas = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, PizzaOrderEntity>();
    static{
        mapOfPizzas.put(10001, new PizzaOrderEntity(101,"Farm House1",5,467.54,"7905947915"));
        mapOfPizzas.put(10002, new PizzaOrderEntity(102,"Farm House2",6,567.54,"7905947916"));
        mapOfPizzas.put(10003, new PizzaOrderEntity(103,"Farm House3",7,667.54,"7905947917"));
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/producer/getPizzaDetails", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Collection<PizzaOrderEntity>> getEmployeeDetails() {
        Collection<PizzaOrderEntity> pizzaList = mapOfPizzas.values();
        System.out.println("I am server with port number "+environment.getProperty("server.port")+". I am hit");
        return new ResponseEntity<Collection<PizzaOrderEntity>>(pizzaList, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

**Consumer**
**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- For Dashboard -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix-dashboard</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId> <!-- to feed the data to the dashboards -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-feign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

**application.properties**

```
feign.circuitbreaker.enabled=true
```

**SpringEurekaConsumerAppPizzaApplication.java- main class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@EnableHystrixDashboard
@EnableFeignClients
public class SpringEurekaConsumerAppPizzaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws RestClientException, IOException {
        HystrixPlugins.getInstance().registerEventNotifier(new CustomHystrixStateNotifier());
        SpringApplication.run(SpringEurekaConsumerAppPizzaApplication.class, args);
    }
```

**PizzaController.java**

```
@RestController
public class PizzaConsumerController {
    
    @Autowired
    private MyFeignClient feignClient;

    @RequestMapping(value="/consumer/getPizzaDetails", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Collection<PizzaOrderEntity>> getPizzaDetails() throws RestClientException, IOException
    {
        ResponseEntity<Collection<PizzaOrderEntity>> pizzasList=null;
        try {

            pizzasList= feignClient.findAllPizzas();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        return pizzasList;
    }
}
```

**MyFeignClient**

```
@FeignClient(name="cst-employee-producer", fallbackFactory = HystrixMyServiceFallbackFactory.class)
public interface MyFeignClient {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/producer/getsPizzaDetails", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    ResponseEntity<Collection<PizzaOrderEntity>> findAllPizzas();

    
}
```

**HystrixMyServiceFallbackFactory.java**

```
public class HystrixMyServiceFallbackFactory implements FallbackFactory<MyFeignClient> {

    @Override
    public MyFeignClient create(Throwable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new MyFeignClient() {

            @Override
            public ResponseEntity<Collection<PizzaOrderEntity>> findAllPizzas() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Map<Integer, PizzaOrderEntity> mapOfPizzas = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, PizzaOrderEntity>();

                mapOfPizzas.put(-1, new PizzaOrderEntity(
                        "OOPs working on it, please try Again after sometime"));

                return new ResponseEntity<Collection<PizzaOrderEntity>>(
                        mapOfPizzas.values(), HttpStatus.OK);
            }

        };

    }
}
```

**CustomHystrixStateNotifier.java**

```
public class CustomHystrixStateNotifier extends HystrixEventNotifier {
      @Override
      public void markEvent(HystrixEventType eventType, HystrixCommandKey commandKey){
          System.out.printf("HystrixStateNotifier: EventType=%s, MethodTriggeredFrom/Key=%s%n", eventType, commandKey);
      }
      
      
    }
```

**PizzaOrderEntity.java**

```
public class PizzaOrderEntity {
    
    Integer orderId;
    String pizzaName;
    Integer quantity;
    Double bill;
    String cutomerContactNumber;
    
    public PizzaOrderEntity(String pizzaName) {
        super();
        
        this.pizzaName = pizzaName;
    }

    public PizzaOrderEntity() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PizzaOrderEntity [orderId=" + orderId + ", pizzaName="
                + pizzaName + ", quantity=" + quantity + ", bill=" + bill
                + ", cutomerContactNumber=" + cutomerContactNumber + "]";
    }

    public PizzaOrderEntity(Integer orderId, String pizzaName,
            Integer quantity, Double bill, String cutomerContactNumber) {
        super();
        this.orderId = orderId;
        this.pizzaName = pizzaName;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.bill = bill;
        this.cutomerContactNumber = cutomerContactNumber;
    }
    
    public Integer getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }
    public void setOrderId(Integer orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }
    public String getPizzaName() {
        return pizzaName;
    }
    public void setPizzaName(String pizzaName) {
        this.pizzaName = pizzaName;
    }
    public Integer getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    public void setQuantity(Integer quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
    public Double getBill() {
        return bill;
    }
    public void setBill(Double bill) {
        this.bill = bill;
    }
    public String getCutomerContactNumber() {
        return cutomerContactNumber;
    }
    public void setCutomerContactNumber(String cutomerContactNumber) {
        this.cutomerContactNumber = cutomerContactNumber;
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
feign.FeignException: status 404 reading MyFeignClient#findAllPizzas(); content:
{"timestamp":1701325896573,"status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/producer/getsPizzaDetails"}
```